# Memoization and naive algorithms - 2 differents answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I have written two recursive algorithms in c++ based on binomial tree. One is very naive and another one with memoization. 
However, both give me different result. The naive one has the good result it is what I expect at the end but very slow.

Assume `n=M=6` I obtain `J_naive (0,0,0) = 0.97916666666666652` and `J_SO (0,0,0,0) = 0.80729166666666652`

Is there anyone seeing a problem on the second algorithm ?

Naive algorithm:

```
double J_naive (double K, double Z, double W)
{
    double J_tmp = exp(100.0);

    if (Z >= 1.0)
        return 0.0;

    //Final condition : Boundaries
    if (K == n)
    {
        double I_WGreaterThanZero = 0.0;
        if (W > 0) I_WGreaterThanZero = 1.0;

        if (Z >= I_WGreaterThanZero) return 0.0;
        return exp(100.0);//Infinity
    }

    //Induction
    else if (K < n)
    {
        double y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
        {
            y = ((double) i)/M;
            if (Z+y <= 1)
                J_tmp = std::min (J_tmp, ((double) n)*y*y +
                                  0.5*J_naive(K+1.0, Z+y, W + 1.0/sqrt(n)) +
                                  0.5*J_naive(K+1.0, Z+y, W - 1.0/sqrt(n)) );
        }
    }

    return J_tmp;
}
```

And the code with memoization

```
typedef vector<vector <bool>> v2dbool;
typedef vector<vector <double>> v2ddouble;
v2dbool seen_[n];
v2ddouble result_[n];

double J_MEMO (unsigned K, unsigned ZM, double W0, int Wdsqrtn)
{
    double J_tmp = exp(100.0);
    double WGreaterThanZero = 0.0;

    double Z = (double) ZM / M;
    double W = W0 + Wdsqrtn * 1./sqrt(n);
    int ind = (K+Wdsqrtn)/2.;

    //Final condition : Boundaries
    if (K == n)
    {

        if (W > 0) WGreaterThanZero = 1.0;
        else WGreaterThanZero = 0.0;

        if (Z >= WGreaterThanZero) return 0.0;
        return exp(100.0);//Infinity
    }

    //Induction
    else if (K < n)
    {
        if (!seen_[K][ZM][ind])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
            {
               if ((double) (ZM+i)/M <= 1)
                 J_tmp = std::min (J_tmp, ((double) n)*i/M*i/M +
                                   1./2.*J_MEMO(K+1, ZM+i, W0, Wdsqrtn+1) +
                                   1./2.*J_MEMO(K+1, ZM+i, W0, Wdsqrtn-1) );
            }

            result_[K][ZM][ind] = J_tmp;
            seen_[K][ZM][ind] = true;
        }
    }

    return result_[K][ZM][ind];
}

void initiateVector ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M+1; j++)
        {
            seen_[i].resize (j+1, std::vector<bool>(i+1, false));
            result_[i].resize (j+1, std::vector<double>(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to convert `J_naive` to have integer parameters, and see what happens.

Comment: The best way to solve this type of problem (after trying to find the issue by just looking at the code) would be to compare the results of each call your code is making (either with working code or with results you worked out on paper), check where the two differ and go through the function line-by-line to see where it's not doing what you want it to. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Dialecticus Only K which is an unsigned but it does not change the result.

Comment: I don't know what you just said. I propose that in `J_naive` you replace `double K, double Z, double W` with `unsigned K, unsigned ZM, double W0, int Wdsqrtn`. Replace all parameters. And see what happens.

Comment: @Dialecticus With your idea I obtain J_naive (0,0,0,0) = J_MEMO (0,0,0,0) = 0.80729166666666652. So J_naive (0,0,0) is not equal to  0.97916666666666652. It is strange since it is the same algortithm ... Do you think it is a problem of double*int ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe there is a loss of data in some double->int conversion somewhere.

Comment: Because I need a very accurate return but at the end there is a gap of roughly 0.2 between the 2 algorithms and it is too big !

Comment: Maybe you could find a difference by comparing every `J_tmp` in `J_naive` with result of corresponding `J_MEMO` call. Must modify `J_naive` to incorporate corresponding `J_MEMO` calls. Break execution on first difference and investigate why they differ.

Answer (score 0):

Without delving too deep into the code I see that in `J_MEMO` you don't have variable `y`, but pass `ZM+i` directly as second parameter. It feels like you should pass `ZM+i/M` there, and not divide `ZM` at function's start to get `Z`. Or just bring back `y`.

Comment: ZM means Z*M which is an int easier to handle. If I do something it is (ZM+i)/M, but it is the role of the variable Z